# Como fazer o Visual Studio reconhecer a diretiva 'use strict'?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, use-strict, ecmascript-5

Aparentemente o Visual Studio não reconhece a diretiva `'use strict'`, pois digitei o código abaixo que atribui valor a uma variável que não foi declarada (algo proibido no *strict mode*) e não houve nenhuma reclamação por parte do IntelliSense.

```javascript
'use strict';

a = 1;
```

Não sei se faz alguma diferença, mas o código foi escrito em um arquivo JavaScript e não dentro de um documento HTML. Então o editor utilizado foi o "Source Code (Text) Editor" e não o "HTML Editor".

Como fazer o Visual Studio reconhecer `'use strict'` e apontar erros no código, como por exemplo nesse caso acima?

Comment: E se você usar um linter? Por exemplo http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1a417c37-4d6f-43ca-b753-6ea6eb5041fd, http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/08/17/using-jshint-inside-visual-studio-the-basics/

Comment: @bfavaretto essa poderia ser uma boa solução, mas será que não há nenhuma opção que se pode ativar dentro do Visual Studio? Já que JavaScript é uma linguagem suportada pelo IDE para fazer aplicações Windows Store, deveria haver alguma opção para isso.

Comment: Não sei, sugeri isso pois está na minha zona de conforto. Não conheço outra solução, só uso Windows de vez em quando, e vs menos ainda...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O '*strict mode*' é um mecanismo de verificação de erros **em tempo de execução**, e por isso ele não é identificado pelo *IntelliSense*. Essa informação está disponível na [documentação das novas características do Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#JavaScript):

> Introduce additional **run-time** constraints and error-checking into your
>   code. For more information, see Strict Mode (JavaScript).

(E nas [novas características do VS 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063.aspx) não há novidades a respeito.)

O [Javascript IntelliSense do VS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx) é bastante bacana, mas ele consegue apenas identificar problemas (ou fazer sugestões) relativas à sintaxe do código (segundo as definição do [ECMAScript 5](http://devproconnections.com/visual-studio-2012/strict-mode-microsoft-visual-studio-2012)). Identificar se uma variável utilizada em uma atribuição foi ou não definida requereria um processo de análise mais complexo (provavelmente similar a uma compilação), e por isso faz sentido o '*strict mode*' só funcionar durante a execução do programa.

O que o Visual Studio é capaz de fazer (sem o uso de plugins) é exibir um diálogo para a exceção gerada *durante a execução* graças ao uso da cláusula "use strict;", conforme ilustra a imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como já citado, talvez algum dos plugins disponíveis forneça indicações mais interessantes diretamente no IntelliSense, mas eu honestamente não sei dizer. Essa [thread do SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362620/how-to-enable-javascript-syntax-checking-in-vs2012) pode ser de alguma ajuda em indicar plugins para isso.